# HSPA 3g modem manager for backtrack/ubuntu

Tags: usb-modem, 3g, modem-manager

I am getting problem with a 3g mobile broadband modem/dongle. Is there any free program available for ubuntu to operate over 3g modem.

I am having problem with instruction came with modem. Is their any other trick to connect modem.

Any command line tool or GUI app please that can be used with different modems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modem Manager GUI is frontend for ModemManager daemon able to control specific modem functions.

Main features:

GTK3 interface
Send and receive SMS messages with messages concatenation
Send USSD request and receive answer in system encoding
Get modem and SIM information (Device info, Operator name, Mode, IMEI, IMSI/ESN, Signal level)
Scan available mobile networks

Install Modem Manager GUI in ubuntu

Open the terminal and run the following comamnds

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

[image]

Comment: You no longer need to add a repo in 14.04 Trusty Tahr, it's available in the software center straight away